# How to store Fetch results in Application's plist file?

Tags: iphone, xcode, nsmutablearray, nsuserdefaults, fetch

I'm querying rows from my sqlite database using Fetch and loading the results into a NSMutableArray myDataArray. What I want to do is to store the values in myDataArray into my application's preferences plist file. But when I run the code below I get the following error:

[NSUserDefaults setObject:forKey:]: Attempt to insert non-property value '(
...(note: contains 50 rows of values)
)' of class '__NSArrayM'.

I'm storing other NSMutableArrays in my plist file using the same method but cannot figure out a way to store the queried database results.

You might ask: why store the values, just requery the database when I need the values again? The reason is I'm pulling random rows from the database and I need to recall the rows exactly as they were originally randomized.

Any help is appreciated,
lq

```
 ...
 fetchResults = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
 self.myDataArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:fetchResults];

 NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
 [userDefaults setObject:self.myDataArray forKey:kFetchResultsArray];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The items in myDataArray are not property list objects, so they can't be automatically serialized to a plist.

From the [NSUserDefaults class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000318-2516) for [`setObject:forKey:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000318-CIHDHAGB):

> The value parameter can be only
>   property list objects: NSData,
>   NSString, NSNumber, NSDate, NSArray,
>   or NSDictionary. For NSArray and
>   NSDictionary objects, their contents
>   must be property list objects. See
>   “What is a Property List?” in Property
>   List Programming Guide.

You may want to consider a mechanism other than user defaults for storing this data. From the [Property List Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/AboutPropertyLists/AboutPropertyLists.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000048i-CH3-54402):

> Many applications require a mechanism
>   for storing information that will be
>   needed at a later time. For situations
>   where you need to store small amounts
>   of persistent data—say less than a few
>   hundred kilobytes—property lists offer
>   a uniform and convenient means of
>   organizing, storing, and accessing the
>   data.
>
> In some situations, the property-list
>   architecture may prove insufficient.
>   If you need a way to store large,
>   complex graphs of objects, objects not
>   supported by the property-list
>   architecture, or objects whose
>   mutability settings must be retained,
>   use archiving. See [Archives and
>   Serializations Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Archiving/Archiving.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000047i) for
>   more information.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. Using an archive doesn't seem like a good solution for me, so what I'm considering is redesigning the app so that rather than pull all 50 rows of data into myDataArray, I will instead pull just the PK_IDs into an array, store them in the plist, then Fetch each row one at a time using the Predicate to call each PK_ID.